# If else not working as intended, is there something wrong with my logic?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, if-statement, foreach

I'm trying to loop through an array and if there are any matching elements, it should push true to a new array else return false.

```js
const wordPerformance = []
const wordsReviewed   = "candy, cattle, cat, call, cheat";
const wordsIncorrect  = "candy, cattle, call, cheat";

wordsReviewed.split(/,\s?/).forEach((word) => {
  if (wordsIncorrect.includes(word)) {
    wordPerformance.push(false);
  } else {
    console.log(word) //unreachable, though 'cat' should be logged
    wordPerformance.push(true);
  }
});

console.log(wordPerformance);
```

By this logic, wordPerformance should return

```
[false, false, true, false, false]
```

however, it is returning

```
[false, false, false, false, false]
```

Maybe there is something I'm not seeing?

Comment: "cat" is included in "cattle". You are not testing for absolute word match, just that substring exists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to first split the `wordsIncorrect` string the same way you did it with the `wordsReviewed` so it does compare whith the item and not include strings which have something at the end like matching "cat" with "cattle"

This is the fixed example

```
const wordPerformance = []
const wordsReviewed = "candy, cattle, cat, call, cheat";
const wordsIncorrect = "candy, cattle, call, cheat";
const wordsIncorrectSplitted = wordsIncorrect.split(/,\s?/);

wordsReviewed.split(/,\s?/).forEach((word) => {
  if (wordsIncorrectSplitted.includes(word)) {
    wordPerformance.push(false);
    } else {
    console.log(word) //unreachable, though 'cat' should be logged
    wordPerformance.push(true);
  }
});

console.log(wordPerformance);
```

[image]

Comment: There is `String.prototype.includes()` also

Comment: hmmm I think you are right. The error then is comparing to the whole string as it includes strings which have something else at the end. I am fixing the answer.

Comment: @charlietfl yep, that's the reason the code didn't throw out an error, it used the .includes() for strings and not arrays

Answer (score 2):

You are forgetting to split your incorrectWords string into an array as well. Right now, you are checking if the string includes the word instead of as an array. As a result, `String.includes` carries out pattern matching across the whole string rather than individual elements. Since every incorrect word includes the pattern `cat` in them, it will think cat is included and return false:

```
const wordPerformance = []
const wordsReviewed   = "candy, cattle, cat, call, cheat";
const wordsIncorrect  = "candy, cattle, call, cheat";

wordsReviewed.split(/,\s?/).forEach((word) => {
  if (wordsIncorrect.split(/,\s?/).includes(word)) { //split incorrectWords
    wordPerformance.push(false);
   } else {
     console.log(word) //unreachable, though 'cat' should be logged
     wordPerformance.push(true);
   }
 });

console.log(wordPerformance);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to split `wordsIncorrect` as well. `if (wordsIncorrect.split(",").includes(word))`

Output:

```
cat
[ false, false, true, false, false ]
```